# How to can I user %title instead of $text->title

Tags: php, html, variables, expression, shortcut

I want to simplify my life and instead of using every time `<?php echo $text->title ?>` I want to use `{%title}` and get the same result. How am I supposed to do this?

I don't want necessarily this expression but something like.

Comment: I would advise AGAINST using PHP short tags because in a nutshell; they don't work reliably. See this article for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use. Using `<?=$title?>` is fine though.

If you really prefer to use custom tags, why not use something like `Twig`, `Blade` or any other `PHP templating engine`?

Comment: Use a templating system like Twig. https://twig.symfony.com/

Comment: @BRO_THOM In all current versions of PHP, `<?=` is supported even if short tags are turned off. `<?` is problematic; `<?=` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a short expression of echo.

```
<?=$text->title?>
```

Also,

In your php.ini change the short_open_tag = Off if it's there to this:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Comment: I can't oveload this with a custome one :)?

Comment: No, you can't for that you need to create your own PHP syntax. which is not possible and if you did it, somehow, while changing configurations files of php then also when update will come, you will face an issue.

Comment: Thank you :) Appreciate